# Start remote XFCE session on second TTY via SSH and X forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, x11forwarding

I don't know very much about ssh and X forwarding (yet) and I am able to run a few graphical apps on the host machine and forward them to my client by using the -X option on ssh. What I really want to do is open a new TTY (say, TTY2) on the client, log in as a local user and then ssh to the server (with a remote user) and start a new xfce desktop session and be able to see it on the client machine, as if I had started the session locally, in order to switch between my local and remote desktops via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>…</kbd>. How can I go about this?

So far I've tried to run `xfce4-session` and `startx` through the remote session but they fail (I'll add the error details asap when I arrive to my workplace).

Comment: as far as I know you can't do that this way. X11 forwarding does forward traffic between X11 server and client, so you need to have the X11 server running on your machine. For this use case, you should use VNC or some derivatives, but there is drawback that you can't run directly it in different TTY.

Comment: Is there an alternative to VNC that goes through ssh or at least is semantic? I don't have that much bandwidth to forward the whole display.

Comment: if your concern is about security, the appropriate solution maybe VNC inside a SSH tunnel. You'll find many descriptions on how to set this, like: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566836/55508. Method #3 is almost what is described here